# Retrieving lat long coordinates in Cartesian circle

Tags: postgis, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm using an OpenStreetMaps database to render a map using leaflet.js. Leaflet has the ability to draw a circle on the map and I would like that circle to be used to drive the measurements used to retrieve all lat long points that fall within it.

However, when I attempt to retrieve this data using ST_Distance (on both geographic and geometric) types, the further south I go, the more the projection those functions apply becomes noticeable on results being returned. Therefore, I'm getting results that fall outside of the circle when they are north or south of the circle, or not getting results that I should be getting when they are east or west of the circle.

I'm storing my lat longs as geometric types because NPgsql does not support the geographic types at this time.

What do I need to do (either in the way I store data or in the way I retrieve it) so that the spherical projection is ignored when retrieving the data and the results match the cartesian circle displayed on the map? As a side note, the distances I'm retrieving the data at will never exceed 50 kilometers.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using EPSG:3857 (spherical mercator projection) as your display coordinate reference system, but EPSG:4326 (equirectangular projection) as the CRS for storing the data and running `ST_Distance`. It's a safe assumption and explains the artifacts you're experiencing.

If you want the displayed circle to match your query results, make both CRSs match. Either display the data in EPSG:4326, or run the `ST_Distance` queries over data in EPSG:3857.